# JavaScript rock, paper, scissor game if/else statement

Tags: javascript, html

Please, I don't know where I might be wrong in my logic. Am building a rock, paper and scissors game. I had my computerPlay() and my playerPlay()  both are working as I expected. where am having issue is in the if/else statement in the playRound(). initially it was working well when I tested it with any of the string in the array. but when I changed the string to playerPlay() so that I can input any of the value I want, I found out that it kept return only the else statement. except when my playerPlay() equals computerPlay() that it will return the actual result I want. Any other result return that 'The typed value is wrong...' as it was stated in the else block, even when the value I typed was correct and when it was wrong. I googled to know if I can get any explanations concerning this but I didn't get a clear explanations. I will really appreciate if anyone can help, thanks.

This is my code

```js
const arr = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];

function computerPlay() {
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)].toUpperCase();
}

function playerPlay() {
  return prompt('Please, Enter your guess: ').toUpperCase();
}

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  if (playerSelection == arr[0] && computerSelection == arr[1] || playerSelection == arr[1] &&
    computerSelection == arr[2] || playerSelection == arr[2] && computerSelection == arr[0]) {
    return 'The Player wins, Computer lost';
  } else if (playerSelection == arr[1] && computerSelection == arr[0] || playerSelection == arr[2] &&
    computerSelection == arr[1] || playerSelection == arr[0] && computerSelection == arr[2]) {
    return 'The player lost, and computer wins'
  } else if (playerSelection == computerSelection) {
    return `it's a draw!`
  } else {
    return "The typed value is wrong, choose rock, paper, scissors to continue the game."
  }
}



console.log('The player: ' + playerPlay())
console.log("The computer: " + computerPlay())
console.log(playRound(computerPlay(), computerPlay()))
```

Comment: You are converting everything to upper case, but your array values are lower case. In your `playRound` you are passing two completely unrelated values: two new results of `computerPlay`. You never use the original `playerPlay()` and the original `computerPlay()`.

Comment: Yes try using uppercase strings in the array aswell.

Comment: @OmPrakash Or simply lower-case everything.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Yes, either way it'll work

Comment: Okay, let me check it out. Thanks.

Comment: For reference, rock paper scissors is cyclic, you can compact a ton of checks: `const names = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']; const computerPlay = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 3); const playerPlay = () => { let input; while((input = names.indexOf(prompt('Please, Enter your guess: '))) === -1); return input; }; const playRound = (a, b) => { const d = (a - b + 3) % 3; return { 0: 'draw', 1: 'player won', 2: 'computer won' }[d];  }; let p = playerPlay(); let c = computerPlay(); console.log(\`player: ${names[p]}, computer: ${names[c]}, ${playRound(p, c)}\`);`

Comment: Your error here is that you're taking the user input and making it uppercase, where the strings in `arr` are lowercase. Change those strings to uppercase letters, or make it change the user input to lowercase (and the computer input).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of your array `arr` is in lower case but you are applying `toUpperCase()` to the user input

So either change the array `arr` in UPPER CASE :

```js
const arr = ['ROCK', 'PAPER', 'SCISSORS'];
```

Or apply `toLowerCase()` to the user input :

```js
return prompt('Please, Enter your guess: ').toLowerCase();
```

Hope that helped

Comment: And also get rid of `toUpperCase()` in `computerPlay()`

Comment: If you apply `toLowerCase()` as you said, you'd also have to change the computer input to `toLowerCase()` as well.

Comment: Am really grateful, it worked. after the correction, I found some  errors at the part where I console.log the functions. I resolved it by saving the functions in variables and then logged the variable and it worked. Thank you so much